# About String method includes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Filter data like this:

```
 cat = ['abc','bcd','efg','ghr'];
 cat.map(i => {i.includes('a')});
 console.log(cat);
```

The result is : `["abc", "bcd", "efg", "ghr"]`

Why isn't `["abc"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the returned results. Remember `.map` does not change the array

What it looks like is you need to [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array, so use `.filter`

```js
var cat = ['abc','bcd','efg','ghr'],
     filteredCats = cat.filter(i => i.includes('a'));
 console.log(filteredCats);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `map` doesn't change the array. It returns an array which, in this case, should be made of booleans. I think you wanted `filter`

```js
let cat = ['abc', 'bcd', 'efg', 'ghr'];
let f = cat.filter(i => i.includes('a'));
console.log(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following improvements that need to be made

- To filter you need to use `filter` function and not `map`
- Both filter and map functions does not update the original array,
  hence, you need to reassign it
- If you are using brackets in arrow function, then you need to add a return. For one liners, there is a default return attached to arrow function.

```js
var cat = ['abc','bcd','efg','ghr'];
 cat = cat.filter(i => i.includes('a'));
 console.log(cat);
```

For references, [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `indexOf()` instead of `includes()` as `includes()` is not recognised in IE browsers and you can also change the arrow function to normal function if you want your code to be executed without any error in IE and other old browsers.

```js
let cat = ['abc', 'bcd', 'efg', 'ghr'];
let res = cat.filter(i => i.indexOf('a') !== -1);
console.log(res);
```